# How to pass array from controller to javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass array (2 dimension) from controller to javascript variable. I use session to pass but this not work. In javascript code I use like this:

```
 var data = '<%= Session["LatLon"] %>';
```

when run project and use inspect element, there is in data :

[image]

how to pass? Can i Pass array with 2 dim with session?

Comment: `var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session.["LatLon"]))';` (and you may need to cast the `Session` value), but I strongly recommend you pass a model to the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting the value into `Session["LatLon"]`, save it as JSON instead of a C# string array.

```
string[][] mystringarr = ...
Session["LatLon"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mystringarr);
```

And in the view use

```
var data = <%= Session["LatLon"] %>;
```

So it will generate something like

```
var data = [["1.0", "1.4"], ["4.6","4.8"]];
```

Using JSON.NET
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently observing is a result of execution `.ToString` method of `Session["LetLon"]` object.

What you intent to receive is `var data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];`.

So you can simply write a correct stringification of your two-dimensional array. I suggest to write simple extension method:

```
public static string ToJsString(this string[,] array) {
     return Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0))
            .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                (sbi, i) => sbi.AppendFormat(i == 0 ? "{0}" : ", {0}",
                    Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(1))
                        .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                            (sbj, j) => sbj.AppendFormat(j == 0 ? "{0}" : ", {0}", array[i,j]),
                            sbj => string.Format("[{0}]", sbj))), 
                sb => string.Format("[{0}]", sb));
}
```

In order to use it write then `var data = <%= ((string[,])Session["LatLon"]).ToJsString() %>`.